# How to programmatically get Head Gaze position and direction in MRTK3 for Hololens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I working with a Microsoft Hololens2 and the Windows Mixed Reality Toolkit (MRTK3). I'm trying to programmatically get hold of the current Gaze direction and origin, which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/gaze?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) for MRTK2:

```
void LogGazeDirectionOrigin()
{
    Debug.Log("Gaze is looking in direction: "
        + CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeDirection);

    Debug.Log("Gaze origin is: "
        + CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeOrigin);
}
```

However, how do I do this in MRTK3?

Searched on Windows forums with no luck

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: To get gaze direction in MRTK3 you have multiple options

1. `FuzzyGazeInteractor`: By default, the `MRTK XR Rig` has the `MRTK Gaze Controller` attached as a child which contains the `FuzzyGazeInteractor`. For more information see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-input/packages/input/eye-tracking#fuzzy-gaze-interactor) documentation by Microsoft. To get gaze origin and direction, you can then do the following, assuming `gazeInteractor` is a reference to the `FuzzyGazeInteractor`:

   ```
   Vector3 gazeOrigin = gazeInteractor.rayOriginTransform.position;
   Vector3 gazeDirection = gazeInteractor.rayOriginTransform.forward;
   ```

2. `ExtendedEyeGazeDataProvider`: In contrast to regular eye tracking, this interface allows extraction of additional, more detailed information such as separated gaze information about left & right eye. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/extended-eye-tracking-unity) documentation by Microsoft in that regard. Getting gaze direction & origin (for example for combined gaze) then works as follows, assuming `gazeProvider` is a reference to the `ExtendedEyeGazeDataProvider`:

```
    var combinedGazeReadingInWorldSpace = extendedEyeGazeDataProvider.GetWorldSpaceGazeReading(ExtendedEyeGazeDataProvider.GazeType.Combined);
    Vector3 gazeOrigin = combinedGazeReadingInWorldSpace.EyePosition;
    Vector3 gazeDirection= combinedGazeReadingInWorldSpace.GazeDirection;
```

3. Regarding **head** gaze: If you are actually interested in the user's head gaze, you can just use information about the `MainCamera`. Head gaze origin & direction could then be estimated using the following approach:

```
    Vector3 headGazeOrigin = Camera.main.transform.position;
    Vector3 headGazeDirection = Camera.main.transform.forward;
```

Also, if no eye tracking is available, the named interfaces will return head gaze as a fallback. You could also disable eye gaze composite completely so that head gaze is always used (see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/11582) github issue as an example).